# Difference between catalog and catalog group in Fiori

Tags: sap-fiori

Could some one please explain me the difference between catalog and catalog group while configuring the Fiori Launchpad?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP Fiori launchpad is the access point to apps on mobile or desktop devices.In Fiori Launch pad Tiles can be selected from catalogs and arranged in groups.You can assign groups and catalogs to roles.

**Catalog** is a set of apps you want to make available for one role. Depending on the role and the catalog assigned to the role, the user can browse through the catalog, choose apps from this catalog, and add them to the entry page of the SAP Fiori launchpad.
Catalog => Apps you would like to deliver for a role

Where as **Group** is a subset of catalog that contains the apps visible on the SAP Fiori launchpad entry page. Which tiles are displayed on a user’s entry page depends on the group assigned to the user’s role.
Group => Apps group as per user's wish

The user can personalize the entry page by adding or removing apps to pre-delivered groups or self-defined groups.

You can find more information about Fiori Launchpad objects here:
[More about Fiori Launchpad Catalogs and Groups](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/cloud_portal_flp/frameset.htm?18b3fc15e6fe487baa99be07c1da82c3.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. As you said, " the user can browse through the catalog, choose apps from this catalog, and add them to the entry page of the SAP Fiori launchpad." so, the user can add apps from the catalog itself then we do we have catalog Group?

Comment: Catalog are the apps we make available to a role. Then this role is assigned to a user. Thus, when the user logs jn initially, no apps are available to any group. He can choose from the apps available to him (from the catalog) and group them as he likes.  For example an employee can have many apps assigned to his role but he can group them as "timesheet apps" , "leave request apps" etc. Kindly let me know if this is clear.

Comment: Perfect explanation ! just one more thing, as per your explanation user is allowed to group apps according to his convenience , but I believe the end user wont be have having access to Fiori launch pad designer where one can create groups. then how the user could group them. kindly,please correct me if I am wrong .Once again thankq so much for your time :)

Comment: Copyright notice: please add credit to the original author as it's a copy/paste of this one (including the typos): https://answers.sap.com/questions/11985305/difference-between-group-and-catalog-in-fiori.html.

Answer (score 0):

Catalogs are apps that are visible for user roles. Groups are sets of apps that are displayed together on the launchpad and are valid for all roles, but some may not be visible, depending on the roles.